# How are we doing on Accessibility and Friendliness?

Tags: discussion

Slightly over three years ago, Joseph Weissman asked the question of what we might do to [improve the accessibility and friendliness](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78/what-steps-can-we-take-to-improve-accessibility-and-friendliness) of the Philosophy S.E.  How do users of the site generally think it is doing in this regard?

It would be good to look at this question in the light of some of the comments made and issues raised in the previous answer:

- How do users of the Philosophy S.E. interpret voting up and down questions and answers, and how do they respond to votes?
- How do users react to close votes, and how are these votes deployed and/or challenged?
- Is there an intended tone for such votes, and is it communicated effectively?
- Do the site's contributors encourage and help develop high quality answers and good questions?
- Is disagreement still handled respectfully and maturely?

I would be interested to hear from users that are relatively new to philosophy and the experiences they have had with the site!